# Google map Current location Balloon overlay?

Tags: android, overlay, currentlocation, popup-balloons

I am creating Google map Current location Balloon overlay.

I used android-mapviewballoons this code to show balloon.

Here Current location display is working. When i click on marker, error will come(BalloonOverlayView 57,38 lines and BalloonItemizedOverlay 87,188,76 lines ).

Where is error i know but i am no understanding that part, Any one please help me

This is LogCat error

```
02-01 05:09:31.606: W/Trace(1250): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-01 05:09:31.636: I/System.out(1250): 6666666666666
02-01 05:09:31.636: I/System.out(1250): 77777777
02-01 05:09:31.646: I/System.out(1250): 7777888888
02-01 05:09:31.656: I/System.out(1250): 33333333
02-01 05:09:31.756: I/System.out(1250): 1111111
02-01 05:09:31.756: W/Trace(1250): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-01 05:09:31.756: E/InputEventReceiver(1250): Exception dispatching input event.
02-01 05:09:31.766: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
02-01 05:09:31.836: D/dalvikvm(1250): GC_CONCURRENT freed 275K, 11% free 3508K/3904K, paused 35ms+27ms, total 163ms
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at com.sygnet.locationingooglemap.BalloonOverlayView.setupView(BalloonOverlayView.java:57)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at com.sygnet.locationingooglemap.BalloonOverlayView.<init>(BalloonOverlayView.java:38)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at com.sygnet.locationingooglemap.BalloonItemizedOverlay.createBalloonOverlayView(BalloonItemizedOverlay.java:87)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at com.sygnet.locationingooglemap.BalloonItemizedOverlay.createAndDisplayBalloonOverlay(BalloonItemizedOverlay.java:188)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at com.sygnet.locationingooglemap.BalloonItemizedOverlay.onTap(BalloonItemizedOverlay.java:76)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.onTap(ItemizedOverlay.java:453)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.onTap(OverlayBundle.java:83)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at com.google.android.maps.MapView$1.onSingleTapUp(MapView.java:358)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at com.google.android.maps.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:562)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onTouchEvent(MapView.java:685)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7239)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2168)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1903)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1953)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1405)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2410)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1901)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7419)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4271)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-01 05:09:31.926: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1250):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-01 05:09:32.006: D/AndroidRuntime(1250): Shutting down VM
02-01 05:09:32.006: W/dalvikvm(1250): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at com.sygnet.locationingooglemap.BalloonOverlayView.setupView(BalloonOverlayView.java:57)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at com.sygnet.locationingooglemap.BalloonOverlayView.<init>(BalloonOverlayView.java:38)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at com.sygnet.locationingooglemap.BalloonItemizedOverlay.createBalloonOverlayView(BalloonItemizedOverlay.java:87)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at com.sygnet.locationingooglemap.BalloonItemizedOverlay.createAndDisplayBalloonOverlay(BalloonItemizedOverlay.java:188)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at com.sygnet.locationingooglemap.BalloonItemizedOverlay.onTap(BalloonItemizedOverlay.java:76)
 02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):    at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.onTap(ItemizedOverlay.java:453)
 02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):    at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.onTap(OverlayBundle.java:83)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView$1.onSingleTapUp(MapView.java:358)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at com.google.android.maps.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:562)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onTouchEvent(MapView.java:685)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7239)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2168)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1903)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1953)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1405)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2410)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1901)
 02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7419)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4271)
 02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
 02-01 05:09:32.096: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is BalloonItemizedOverlay.java

```
 public abstract class BalloonItemizedOverlay<Item extends OverlayItem> extends ItemizedOverlay<Item> {

private static final long BALLOON_INFLATION_TIME = 300;
private static Handler handler = new Handler();

private MapView mapView;
private BalloonOverlayView<Item> balloonView;
private View clickRegion;
private View closeRegion;
private int viewOffset;
final MapController mc;
private Item currentFocusedItem;
private int currentFocusedIndex;

private boolean showClose = true;
private boolean showDisclosure = false;
private boolean snapToCenter = true;
private static boolean isInflating = false;

public BalloonItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, MapView mapView) {
    super(defaultMarker);
    this.mapView = mapView;
    viewOffset = 0;
    mc = mapView.getController();
}

public void setBalloonBottomOffset(int pixels) {
    viewOffset = pixels;
}
public int getBalloonBottomOffset() {
    return viewOffset;
}

protected boolean onBalloonTap(int index, Item item) {
    return false;
}

protected void onBalloonOpen(int index) {}

@Override
public final boolean onTap(int index) {

    handler.removeCallbacks(finishBalloonInflation);
    isInflating = true;
    handler.postDelayed(finishBalloonInflation, BALLOON_INFLATION_TIME);
    System.out.println("6666666666666");
    currentFocusedIndex = index;
    currentFocusedItem = createItem(index);
    setLastFocusedIndex(index);

    onBalloonOpen(index);
    createAndDisplayBalloonOverlay();

    if (snapToCenter) {
        mc.animateTo(currentFocusedItem.getPoint());
    }

    return true;
}

protected BalloonOverlayView<Item> createBalloonOverlayView() {
    System.out.println("77777777");
    return new BalloonOverlayView<Item>(getMapView().getContext(), getBalloonBottomOffset());
}

protected MapView getMapView() {
    System.out.println("7777888888");
    return mapView;

}

public void hideBalloon() {
    if (balloonView != null) {
        balloonView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        System.out.println("888888");
    }
    currentFocusedItem = null;
}

private void hideOtherBalloons(List<Overlay> overlays) {

    for (Overlay overlay : overlays) {
        if (overlay instanceof BalloonItemizedOverlay<?> && overlay != this) {
            ((BalloonItemizedOverlay<?>) overlay).hideBalloon();
            System.out.println("88886666666666688");
        }
    }       
}

public void hideAllBalloons() {
    if (!isInflating) {
        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        if (mapOverlays.size() > 1) {
            hideOtherBalloons(mapOverlays);
        }
        hideBalloon();
    }
}

private OnTouchListener createBalloonTouchListener() {
    return new OnTouchListener() {

        double startX;
        double startY;

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

//              View l =  ((View) v.getParent()).findViewById(R.id.balloon_main_layout);
            Drawable d = v.getBackground();

            //Event Action Down
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                int[] states = {android.R.attr.state_pressed};
                if (d.setState(states)) {
                    d.invalidateSelf();
                    System.out.println("12122121212");
                }
                startX = event.getX();
                startY = event.getY();
                System.out.println("1111222211112222");
                return true;
            } 

            //Event Action Up
            else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                int newStates[] = {};
                if (d.setState(newStates)) {
                    d.invalidateSelf();
                    System.out.println("0000011111");
                }
                if (Math.abs(startX - event.getX()) < 40 && Math.abs(startY - event.getY()) < 40 ) {
                    // call overridden method
                    onBalloonTap(currentFocusedIndex, currentFocusedItem);
                    System.out.println("12345678");
                }
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }               
        }
    };
}

@Override
public Item getFocus() {
    return currentFocusedItem;
}

@Override
public void setFocus(Item item) {
    super.setFocus(item);   
    currentFocusedIndex = getLastFocusedIndex();
    currentFocusedItem = item;
    if (currentFocusedItem == null) {
        hideBalloon();
    } else {
        createAndDisplayBalloonOverlay();
    }   
}

private boolean createAndDisplayBalloonOverlay(){
    boolean isRecycled;
    if (balloonView == null) {
        balloonView = createBalloonOverlayView();
        clickRegion = (View) balloonView.findViewById(R.id.balloon_inner_layout);

        clickRegion.setOnTouchListener(createBalloonTouchListener());
        closeRegion = (View) balloonView.findViewById(R.id.balloon_close);
        if (closeRegion != null) {
            if (!showClose) {
                closeRegion.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                System.out.println("aaaaaaaa");
            } else {
                closeRegion.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        hideBalloon();  
                        System.out.println("bbbbbbb");
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        if (showDisclosure && !showClose) {
            View v = balloonView.findViewById(R.id.balloon_disclosure);
            if (v != null) {
                v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                System.out.println("cccccccc");
            }
        }
        isRecycled = false;
    } 
    else {
        isRecycled = true;
    }

    balloonView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    if (mapOverlays.size() > 1) {
        hideOtherBalloons(mapOverlays);
    }

    if (currentFocusedItem != null)
        balloonView.setData(currentFocusedItem);

    GeoPoint point = currentFocusedItem.getPoint();
    MapView.LayoutParams params = new MapView.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, point,
            MapView.LayoutParams.BOTTOM_CENTER);
    params.mode = MapView.LayoutParams.MODE_MAP;

    balloonView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    System.out.println("dddddddd");
    if (isRecycled) {
        balloonView.setLayoutParams(params);
    } 
    else {
        mapView.addView(balloonView, params);
    }

    return isRecycled;
} 

public void setShowClose(boolean showClose) {
    this.showClose = showClose;
}

public void setShowDisclosure(boolean showDisclosure) {
    this.showDisclosure = showDisclosure;
}

public void setSnapToCenter(boolean snapToCenter) {
    this.snapToCenter = snapToCenter;
}

public static boolean isInflating() {
    return isInflating;
}

private static Runnable finishBalloonInflation = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        isInflating = false;
    }
};

}
```

This is BalloonOverlayView.java

```
public class BalloonOverlayView<Item extends OverlayItem> extends FrameLayout  {

LinearLayout layout;
private TextView title;
MainActivity main;
private CharSequence tvLocation;


public BalloonOverlayView(Context context, int balloonBottomOffset) {

    super(context);

    setPadding(10, 0, 10, balloonBottomOffset);

    layout = new LimitLinearLayout(context);
    layout.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

    setupView(context, layout);

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.NO_GRAVITY;

    addView(layout, params);
}

protected void setupView(Context context, ViewGroup parent) {
    try {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.balloon_overlay, parent);
    title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.balloon_item_title);
    System.out.println("00000000000");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("1111111");
        title.setText(tvLocation);
    }

//      title.setText(tvLocation);
}

public void setData(Item item) {
    layout.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    setBalloonData(item, layout);
    System.out.println("1113333");
}

protected void setBalloonData(Item item, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (item.getTitle() != null) {
        title.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        title.setText(item.getTitle());
        title.setText(tvLocation);

        System.out.println("222222222");
    } else {
        title.setText("");
        title.setVisibility(GONE);
        System.out.println("111222222");
    }
}

private class LimitLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

    private static final int MAX_WIDTH_DP = 280;

    final float SCALE = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    public LimitLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        System.out.println("33333333");
    }

    public LimitLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        System.out.println("444444");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int mode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        int measuredWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int adjustedMaxWidth = (int)(MAX_WIDTH_DP * SCALE + 0.5f);
        int adjustedWidth = Math.min(measuredWidth, adjustedMaxWidth);
        int adjustedWidthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(adjustedWidth, mode);
        System.out.println("555555555");
        super.onMeasure(adjustedWidthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}

}
```

This is balloon_overlay.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/balloon_main_layout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/balloon_overlay_bg_selector"
android:minWidth="200dip"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="25dip"
android:paddingLeft="10dip"
android:paddingRight="0dip"
android:paddingTop="0dip" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/balloon_inner_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="40dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/balloon_item_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
            android:textSize="@string/txtsize"
            android:text="" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/balloon_disclosure"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/balloon_disclosure"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/balloon_close"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="5dip"
    android:paddingTop="5dip"
    android:src="@drawable/balloon_overlay_close" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code , it's working fine for me :

```
public class CurrentLocationOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>{

    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mapOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    private MapView mapView;
    private Context context;

    //pin point drawable
    private Drawable marker;

    //balloon background
    private Drawable viewDrawable;

    private LinearLayout viewBubble;

    public CurrentLocationOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param defaultMarker
     * @param activity
     * @param context
     * @param mapView
     */
    public CurrentLocationOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker , Context context, MapView mapView) {
        this(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
        this.mapView = mapView;
        this.context = context;
        marker = defaultMarker;
        growPopUpAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.grow_from_bottom);
        viewDrawable =  context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.currlocpopup);
    }


    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return mapOverlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return mapOverlays.size();
    }


    /**
     * 
     * @param gp
     * @param title
     * @param msg
     */
    public void addOverlay(GeoPoint gp , String title , String msg) {
        OverlayItem overlay = new OverlayItem(gp, title, msg); 
        mapOverlays.add(overlay);
        this.populate();
    }


    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
        final int position = index;
            Log.v("Overlay index", "" + position);
            GeoPoint p = mapOverlays.get(index).getPoint();
            addBubble(p , position);
        return true;
    }



    /**
     * 
     * @param point
     * @param mapView
     */
    private void addBubble(GeoPoint point , int index) {
        dimissbubble(mapView);
        // if there isn't any bubble on the screen enter
        if (viewBubble == null) {
            viewBubble = new LinearLayout(context);
            viewBubble.bringToFront();
            viewBubble.setBackgroundDrawable(viewDrawable);

            TextView tv = new TextView(context);
            tv.setText(mapOverlays.get(index).getTitle());
            tv.setTextSize(16);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);


            viewBubble.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

            viewBubble.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);

            viewBubble.addView(tv);

            MapView.LayoutParams mvlp = new MapView.LayoutParams(
                    MapView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    MapView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, point,
                    0,  -marker.getIntrinsicHeight(),
                    MapView.LayoutParams.BOTTOM_CENTER);

            mvlp.mode = MapView.LayoutParams.MODE_MAP;

            mapView.addView(viewBubble, mvlp);
            viewBubble.startAnimation(growPopUpAnim);

            // And the event.
            viewBubble.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                // When we touch the bubble it is removed. And make null
                // viewBubble to reuse it.
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mapView.removeView(viewBubble);
                    viewBubble = null;
                }
            });
        }
    }


    /**
     * 
     * @param mapView
     */
    private void dimissbubble(MapView mapView) {
        if (viewBubble != null) {
            mapView.removeView(viewBubble);
            viewBubble = null;
        }
    }
}
```

add this :

```
 GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint(
                        (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                        (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

CurrentLocationOverlay currentLocationOverlay = new  CurrentLocationOverlay(mDrawable,context, mapView);
currentLocationOverlay.addOverlay(p ,"Current Location" , "");
mapView.getOverlays().add(currentLocationOverlay);
```

Comment: Where i create (R.anim.grow_from_bottom) this. previously my net is not working.please help me

Comment: and also this one : viewBubble.startAnimation(growPopUpAnim);

Comment: main program some problem will come, Cannot instantiate the type CurrentLocationOverlay.   The method addOverlay(GeoPoint, String, String) in the type CurrentLocationOverlay is not applicable for the arguments (OverlayItem). Here what can i do

Comment: // Creating an instance of ItemizedOverlay to mark the current location in the map
  CurrentLocationOverlay currentLocationOverlay = new CurrentLocationOverlay(drawable);
  
  // Creating an item to represent a mark in the overlay
  OverlayItem currentLocation = new OverlayItem(point, "Current Location", "Latitude : " + latitude + ", Longitude:" + longitude);

  // Adding the mark to the overlay
  currentLocationOverlay.addOverlay(currentLocation);
  
  // Clear Existing overlays in the map
  mapOverlays.clear();

Comment: Cannot instantiate the type CurrentLocationOverlay this is error. please give me a main code

Comment: CurrentLocationOverlay(mDrawable,context, mapView) context error came

Comment: use youActivityName.this instead of context

Comment: new  CurrentLocationOverlay(drawable, context, mapView); Same error came(Cannot instantiate the type CurrentLocationOverlay)

Comment: is your CurrentLocationOverlay class is abstract ?

Comment: Runtime error came 02-01 08:35:37.051: E/AndroidRuntime(3600): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sygnet.locationingooglemap/com.sygnet.locationingooglemap.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: please help me i am new joining